# Как в процессе работы кода заставить его изменить имеющиеся ссылку?

Tags: php, парсер

Нужно изменить вот эту ссылку в коде из переменной.

```
$link = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Neryungri&mode=json&units=metric&lang=ru&cnt=1&APPID='.$weath_token;
```

Суть в том что в переменной будет заключён текст на русском языке который нужно написать на английском (это будут города). После чего результат нужно будет вставить на то место где стоит Neryungri в ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cities_EN = ""; // :D
foreach ($cities_RU as $city){
    switch ($cities_RU){
        case "Москва":
            $cities_EN .= "Moscow,";
        .......
            break;
    }
}
int cit = strlen($cities_EN);
if(cit > 0){
    cit = substr($cities_EN, cit - 1);
}
$link = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=".$cities_EN."&mode=json&units=metric&lang=ru&cnt=1&APPID='.$weath_token;
```

Comment: Без знания пхп. Так что если что-то не так понял, поправьте